# MVC Pattern JButton ActionListener not Responding

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

So I'm trying to create a simple test program where the user can enter something into a JTextField, click the "add" JButton, and a JTextArea will add the users string to the the JTextArea (continuously appending with new line).

I added the actionListener for the button and have a stateChanged and an update method, but nothing happens when I click the add button. No errors either. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's my code:

MVCTester (main)

```
public class MVCTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MVCController myMVC = new MVCController();
        MVCViews myViews = new MVCViews();
        myMVC.attach(myViews);
    }

}
```

MVCController

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class MVCController {

    MVCModel model;
    ArrayList<ChangeListener> listeners;
    public MVCController(){
        model = new MVCModel();
        listeners = new ArrayList<ChangeListener>();
    }

    public void update(String input){
        model.setInputs(input);
          for (ChangeListener l : listeners)
          {
             l.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
          }
    }
     public void attach(ChangeListener c)
     {
        listeners.add(c);
     }
}
```

MVCModel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MVCModel {
    private ArrayList<String> inputs;


    MVCModel(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getInputs(){
        return inputs;
    }

    public void setInputs(String input){
        inputs.add(input);
    }

}
```

MVCViews

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class MVCViews implements ChangeListener {


    private JTextField input;
    private JTextArea echo;
    private ArrayList<String> toPrint = new ArrayList<String>();
    MVCController controller;

    MVCViews(){
        controller = new MVCController();
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton addButton = new JButton("add");
        echo = new JTextArea(10,20);
        echo.append("Hello there! \n");
        echo.append("Type something below!\n");
        myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        myPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        input = new JTextField();
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(echo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                controller.update(input.getText());
            }

        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        toPrint = controller.model.getInputs();

        for(String s: toPrint){
            echo.append(s + "\n");
        }

    }   
}
```

This is my first time trying to follow MVC format, so there might be issues with the model itself as well. Feel free to point them out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does your JTextArea show the 'Hello There!' and 'Type Someyhing Below" lines?

Comment: @user2693587 Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller within the GUI is not the same controller that is created in main. Note how many times you call `new MVCController()` in your code above -- it's **twice**. Each time you do this, you're creating a new and distinct controller -- not good. Use only **one**. You've got to pass the one controller into the view. You can figure out how to do this. (hint, a setter or constructor parameter would work).

hint 2: this could work: `MVCViews myViews = new MVCViews(myMVC);`

one solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MVCTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MVCController myMVC = new MVCController();
      MVCViews myViews = new MVCViews(myMVC);
      myMVC.attach(myViews);  
      // myViews.setController(myMVC); // or this could do it
   }
}

class MVCController {
   MVCModel model;
   ArrayList<ChangeListener> listeners;

   public MVCController() {
      model = new MVCModel();
      listeners = new ArrayList<ChangeListener>();
   }

   public void update(String input) {
      model.setInputs(input);
      for (ChangeListener l : listeners) {
         l.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
      }
   }

   public void attach(ChangeListener c) {
      listeners.add(c);
   }
}

class MVCModel {
   private ArrayList<String> inputs;

   MVCModel() {
      inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getInputs() {
      return inputs;
   }

   public void setInputs(String input) {
      inputs.add(input);
   }
}

class MVCViews implements ChangeListener {
   private JTextField input;
   private JTextArea echo;
   private ArrayList<String> toPrint = new ArrayList<String>();
   MVCController controller;

   MVCViews(final MVCController controller) {
      // !! controller = new MVCController();
      this.controller = controller;
      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      JButton addButton = new JButton("add");
      echo = new JTextArea(10, 20);
      echo.append("Hello there! \n");
      echo.append("Type something below!\n");
      myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      myPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      input = new JTextField();
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.add(echo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (controller != null) {
               controller.update(input.getText());
            }
         }
      });
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void setController(MVCController controller) {
      this.controller = controller;
   }

   @Override
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      if (controller != null) {
         toPrint = controller.model.getInputs();
         for (String s : toPrint) {
            echo.append(s + "\n");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But if I declare and instantiate MVCModel in MVCViews, how can I reach the update method in MVCContoller? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @aurora91: **Don't** instantiate controller in the view but instead **pass** it in. see edit.

Comment: @aurora91: have you figured it out yet?

Comment: Ok, I updated MVCViews constructor to take parameter final MVCController myMVC and use that to call update in my button action listener. But I'm still ending up at the same result. But now only main instantiates MVCController. Let me know if you would like me to edit my code.

Comment: @aurora91: hello? Going to bed.

Comment: Yeah, your code seems to be what I updated mine too as well. Except you also took out MVCModel from MVCViews (which I understand I was wrong). But there's still no response from clicking the add button.

Comment: @aurora91: funny, it works fine for me. Please run my code whole and re-test.

Comment: Sorry, was looking over your code and comparing to mine. Feel free to go to bed if you need to, I don't want to inconvenience you. You've already helped a lot.

Comment: I'll be damned... it your's worked. I'll look over what I missed in mine and compare. Thanks so much for your help once again!